# How many images with bounding boxes are in the ImageNet object detection dataset?

Tags: dataset, object-detection

I am trying to understand how many images with object-detection bounding boxes are in ImageNet dataset, and how many objects are there in these images.

In [MS-COCO paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.0312.pdf), it says:

> "Recently, a detection challenge has been created from 200 object
> categories using a subset of 400,000 images from ImageNet. An
> impressive 350,000 objects have been labeled using bounding boxes."

Are there less objects than images? Later in the paper it says:

> MS COCO contains considerably more object instances per image (7.7) as
> compared to ImageNet (3.0) and PASCAL (2.3)

In the ImageNet [website](http://image-net.org/about-stats) it says 1,034,908 images with bounding boxes.

**These numbers seem to conflict.**

What am I missing? Does anyone know the correct image and object numbers?

Note: I'm not looking for the number of images with classification annotations, just the object detection annotations.

Answer (score 0):

From the ILSVRC 2014 [website](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2014/) that in the image detection dataset there are 476,688 images with 534,309 objects